# More than one User ID at start up

Tags: startup

I Use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3, with the additional backports PPA (to get LTS). in three desktops PCs and one laptop.

But, only in one of the three desktops, I get a weird message from the startup list of tasks: Just before the main graphic screen appears, I can see clearly two different User ID (138 and 143) each time I power on that computer.

The lines are:

```
started user manager for UID 138
started user manager for UID 143
```

Why is this?

Why it is not the same in the other PCs?

How can I change this?

Comment: Have you looked at the password information for these UIDs (for example `getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 == 138 || $3 == 143'`)?

Comment: The only have I get from thar command is: `smmsp:x:138:145:Mail Submission Program,,,:/var/lib/sendmail:/bin/false
gdm:x:143:149:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false`